# How can I create a method that uses the Scanner class to register the user's input?

Tags: java

I need the user to input a radius value, so that, I can calculate the area/perimeter of a circle. Since I can't really understand the Scanner class, I can't seem to make it work. I would love some feedback to fix my method.

```
public static double leeTeclado() {
    Scanner radio = new Scanner(System.in); // Creamos el objeto de scanner
    System.out.println("Escribe el valor del radio: "); // Pedimos al usuario que introduzca un valor
    radio = radio.nextDouble();       // El Scanner lee el valor


    try {
        radio = Double.parseDouble(radio.nextDouble());
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error en la lectura de datos");
    }
    return radio;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you're doing wrong is assigning a double value to an instance of Scanner. 
that doesn't really work. 
an example of correct code would be

```java
static double getRadius () {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter radius value : ");

    // you will store the value of the radius in this variable 
    double radius;

    // try-catch block for eventual number format exceptions 
    try {
        radius = scan.nextDouble();
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }

    // if no exception occured, return the value
    return radius;
}
```

to better understand the Scanner class, take a look at these links : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html
https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_user_input.asp

hope I helped you

Answer (score 0):

This line is a problem because you assign a `double` to an instance of the `Scanner` class: `radio = radio.nextDouble();`

Try to define another variable of type `double` and assign the result of `radio.nextDouble()` to it:

```
public static double leeTeclado() {
    Scanner radio = new Scanner(System.in); // Creamos el objeto de scanner
    System.out.println("Escribe el valor del radio: "); // Pedimos al usuario que introduzca un valor
    double valor = 0.0;
    try {
       valor = radio.nextDouble();       // El Scanner lee el valor
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return valor;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The **nextFloat()** or **nextDouble()** method of **java.util.Scanner** can be used for implementing the desired requirement of reading floatig point input.

**Working demo of nextFloat() / nextDouble():**

```
// File name: Demo.java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the radius of circle: ");
        double radius = sc.nextDouble();

        double diameter = (radius * 2);
        double perimeter = ((22 * diameter) / 7);
        double area = ( (22 * radius * radius) / 7);
        System.out.println("Radius = " + radius);
        System.out.println("Diameter = " + diameter);
        System.out.println("Perimeter = " + perimeter);
        System.out.println("Area = " + area);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
> javac Demo.java

> java Demo

Enter the radius of circle: 4
Radius = 4.0
Diameter = 8.0
Perimeter = 25.142857142857142
Area = 50.285714285714285
```